# Foreign keys in model

Tags: django, model, foreign-keys

I am creating a form to catch registration information into Competitors database. From that database, I want to create group where competitors can be organized and compete again each other.

Models.py

```
  
class Group1(models.Model):
  flname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  Weight = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(50), MaxValueValidator(300)], default= 0)
  rank = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  point = models.IntegerField


class Competitors(models.Model):
  flname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  Weight = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(50), MaxValueValidator(300)])
  rank = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  Group = models.ForeignKey(Group1, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Traceback:

```
Exception Type: OperationalError at /admin/appbjjtournament/competitors/
Exception Value: no such column: appbjjtournament_competitors.Group_id
```

I deleted, makemigration, and migrate, but the error still persists.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful about deleting migrations. The migrations are saved to the database, and when you are making a new migration the new migrations are compared with the existing migrations, in order to verify that things go as expected.

When you delete saved migrations without updating the database you will get errors similar to the one above. I.e migrations in the code are not compliant with the migrations saved to the database.

If it is a learning project and you are the only person working on it, then I would suggest to delete everything from the database and start from scratch with a brand new database. You can also delete all the existing migrations.